# HP server will not enter standby

Tags: linux, standby, hp-proliant

I have been trying to setup a server to enter standby when it does not need to run. However I just noticed I can not actually get it to go into standby at all.

The server is a HP proliant DL360 G5 running Linux mint.

I have been going through the BIOS to see if I need to enable this however I have yet to find anything.

Currently if I try to place the Server into StandBy it does nothing at all and just continues running. Any Ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that ACPI is enabled in the BIOS/UEFI. After that you need to install ACPI-support in the OS. Linux mint aught to have the acpi-package installed by default but it's always good to check. Once you have acpi-support you can initiate suspend and hibernate commands with the help of various tools.